# Spring-boot: LocalDateTime controller param (really exhausted)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jackson

I'm using `LocalDateTime` controller params in order to receive dates:

```
@RequestMapping(
    path = EspaiDocConstants.Endpoints.FO_BOINTERFACE_REQUEST_MAPPING_AUDITS,
    method = RequestMethod.GET,
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
)
public Collection<Audit> listAudits(
    @RequestParam(value = "deadline", required = false)
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
        LocalDateTime deadline) {}
```

However, it's running against an `"No primary or default constructor”` issue.

According [this workaround](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13362), I need to add this code in order to avoid that:

```
@ModelAttribute
LocalDateTime initLocalDate() {
    return LocalDateTime.now();
}
```

and then, add `@ModelAttribute` on my `deadline` param:

```
public Collection<Audit> listAudits(
    @RequestParam(value = "deadline", required = false)
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
    @ModelAttribute
        LocalDateTime deadline) {}
```

Now, it's not crashing, but my `deadline` param value is always `LocalDateTime.now()`, regardless of param value. I'm testing with this request:

```
https://localhost:8080/bo/audits?deadline=2000-10-31T01:30:00.000-05:00
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

With the `@ModelAttribute` Annotation on method level you add and bind implicit the return value of the method to each model of each request-method. So you don't have to add the object via model.addAttribute("key", value) in each `GET, POST, PUT` and `DELETE`-method.

So for your use case it is not necessary to have the `@ModelAttribute`-annotated method.

```
public Collection<Audit> listAudits(
    @RequestParam(value = "deadline", required = false)
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
    LocalDateTime deadline) { ... }
```

*should* work.

But maybe it is necessary to encode the colon in the request parameter client-side.

Comment: Without `@ModelAttribute` it's getting me: `No primary or default constructor found for class java.time.LocalDateTime`

Comment: It is because LocalDateTime doesn't provide a suitable constructor. Spring tries to create an object with `new LocalDateTime(..)` but can't find a matching constructor. When using the `@ModelAttribute` annotated method Spring inserts the current local date time (from the `.now()` method.) Therefore the datetime from the request doesn't match the dateTime inside the java method. I think you have to implement your own `LocalDatetimeFormatter`